# Mounting all partitions on hard disk automatically on Linux Mint

Tags: linux, automounting

**Issue**
I have a Linux Mint installation. Every time that I boot, I need to manually mount the two partitions on my computer(`New volume D` and `Drive C`). If I  don't do this, these drives don't show up anywhere. I want to know if there is some way to automate this process.

**Goal**
Automatically mounting all the partitions on the hard disk each time I boot.

**Specs**
Linux Mint 14 dual boot with Windows XP SP3

Comment: http://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?p=135082,http://community.linuxmint.com/tutorial/view/92

Comment: As discussed in the accepted previous answer, the /etc/fstab file will help you accomplish that. Please take a look at [genfstab](https://projects.archlinux.org/arch-install-scripts.git/tree/genfstab.in) which, as suggested, uses blkid to create one automatically.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can do this through the file `/etc/fstab`. Take a look at this [link](http://www.tuxfiles.org/linuxhelp/fstab.html). This [tutorial](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-finding-using-uuids-to-update-fstab/) also has good details.

#### Example steps

First you need to find out the UUID of the hard drives. You can use the command `blkid` for this. For example:

```
% sudo blkid
/dev/sda1: TYPE="ntfs" UUID="A0F0582EF0580CC2"
/dev/sda2: UUID="8c2da865-13f4-47a2-9c92-2f31738469e8" SEC_TYPE="ext2" TYPE="ext3"
/dev/sda3: TYPE="swap" UUID="5641913f-9bcc-4d8a-8bcb-ddfc3159e70f"
/dev/sda5: UUID="FAB008D6B0089AF1" TYPE="ntfs"
/dev/sdb1: UUID="32c61b65-f2f8-4041-a5d5-3d5ef4182723" SEC_TYPE="ext2" TYPE="ext3"
/dev/sdb2: UUID="41c22818-fbad-4da6-8196-c816df0b7aa8" SEC_TYPE="ext2" TYPE="ext3"
```

The output from the `blkid` command above can be used to identify the hard drive when adding entries to `/etc/fstab`.

Next you need to edit the `/etc/fstab` file. The lines in this file are organized as follows:

```
UUID={YOUR-UID}    {/path/to/mount/point}               {file-system-type}    defaults,errors=remount-ro 0       1
```

Now edit the file:

```
% sudo vi /etc/fstab
```

And add a file like this, for example:

```
UUID=41c22818-fbad-4da6-8196-c816df0b7aa8  /disk2p2      ext3    defaults,errors=remount-ro 0       1
```

Save the file and then reprocess the file with the `mount -a` command.

#### Windows partitions

To mount an ntfs partition you'll need to do something like this in your `/etc/fstab` file:

```
/dev/sda2   /mnt/excess ntfs-3g    permissions,locale=en_US.utf8    0   2
```

Comment: the two partitions `/dev/sda5` and `dev/sda6` are not listed in `fstab` file and in the `blkid` command. why?

Comment: okay. i got it. it is because it is a windows partition that is there in /media

Comment: Windows partitions you'll need to use the dev/sda* to mount them, also you'll need to specify ntfs-3g for the file-system-type I believe.

Comment: This answer does not address OP's request. it provides instructions on how to manually configure mint to re-mount on boot a specific set of partitions on a specific set of drives. The question was how to automount all partitions on all drives. What OP needs is a script that searches for all available partitions and then mounts any it finds. Such scripts do exist

Answer (score 17):

You can do this by the simplest way. Go to:

- Menu -> Disks (app)
- Select the volume you want to mount, and click on its options
- Select "Edit Mount Options" -> And make sure you select "Mount at Startup" in the drive.

Comment: Sometime gui makes sense or it makes easy to do these things.

Comment: Oh, Holly S***, Nice!!!

Comment: Wysiwyg solution, better for beginners.

Comment: Seriously this is the best answer.. so easy and less error prone

Answer (score 3):

If you have a lot of partitions to be mounted, maybe you need a script like I did.

```
# ! python
# mount all partition by neoedmund
from subprocess import Popen
from subprocess import PIPE

def getCol(col, line):
    p1 = line.find(col)
    if p1<0 : return ""
    p2 = p1 + len(col) + 1
    p3 = line.find('"',p2+1)
    return line[p2+1:p3]

data_stream = Popen(["/bin/lsblk", "-P", "-o", "FSTYPE,UUID,MOUNTPOINT,KNAME"], stdout=PIPE)
data=[]
for line in data_stream.stdout:
    fstype = getCol("FSTYPE", line)
    if fstype=="": continue # no fs
    mountpoint = getCol("MOUNTPOINT", line)
    if mountpoint!="":continue  # already mounted   
    uuid = getCol("UUID", line)
    kname = getCol("KNAME", line)
    data.append((kname, uuid))

print("### mount script ###")
for (kname,uuid) in data:
    print("mkdir /media/%s-%s"%(kname, uuid))
    print("mount /dev/%s /media/%s-%s" %(kname, kname, uuid))

print("### umount script ###")
for (kname,uuid) in data:
    print("umount /dev/%s" %(kname))
```

It is a python script, depends on "/bin/lsblk" , save the output to two  shell scripts for mount and umount.

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in $(lsblk -r |awk '{ print $1 }'|grep -v md |grep -v loop |grep .*[[:digit:]]|sort|uniq;); 
do
    if [ -z  "$(grep  $i /proc/mounts)" ]
    then  
        mkdir /mnt/$i;
        mount /dev/$i /mnt/$i
    fi
done
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you could explain exactly what your command does.

Comment: Putting a huge sequence of commands and control structures on the same line doesn't really make your code a *one-liner*. It just makes it unecessarily harder to understand...

Answer (score 0):

Backup of current fstab:

```
#cp -a /etc/fstab /etc/fstab.bk
```

process the output of **lsblk -f** using **sed** and **awk** and redirect output to fstab:

```
#lsblk -f|sed 's/\[SWAP]/swap /g'|awk '/(-)/{printf"UUID=%-36s %-23s %-7s defaults 
           0 0\n", $3, ($4==""?mnt"NR:$4), $2}'>/etc/fstab
```

mount the new mount points by invoking

```
#mount -a
```